# how to get fields tables of an acces db into a list box?`

Tags: c#, oledb

need to create a form in which i hav to browse and open mdb files ---> i did this part usin oprnfile dialogue!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog oDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    oDlg.Title = "Select MDB";
    oDlg.Filter = "MDB (*.Mdb)|*.mdb";
    oDlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

    string dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    oDlg.InitialDirectory = dir;

    DialogResult result = oDlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = oDlg.FileName.ToString();
    }

    string strFileName = oDlg.FileName.ToString();

    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();

    DataTable schemaTable;
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Mode=Share Deny None;Data Source="+strFileName;
    cn.Open();

    schemaTable = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(

    OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,

    new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

    //List the table name from each row in the schema table.

    for (int i = 0; i < schemaTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         strTableName = schemaTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
        listBox1.Items.Add(strTableName);
    }

    //Explicitly close - don't wait on garbage collection.

    cn.Close();

}
```

this is my code so far!!!

now i need to make 3 list boxes!!

1st one to display the table names of the db<-----done till here!!!!

2nd to to display field names when clicked on table name!!!---> to b done! 
3rd to display attributes on fiels on clickin on it!!!---> to b done!

v can edit the attribute values and on clickin of save button it should update the database!!!

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the columns array of your schemaTable object:

```
for(int i=0;i<schemaTable.Columns.Length;i++)
    listBox2.Items.Add(schemaTable.Columns[i].ToString());
```